# Laravel 4 how to apply title and meta information to each page with blade master page

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Trying to apply an individual title and meta description to my websites pages, but I'm not sure if the way I'm attempting is very clean.

**master.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{{ $title }}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{{ $description }}">
</head>
```

**individual page**

```
@extends('layouts.master')
<?php $title = "This is an individual page title"; ?>
<?php $description = "This is a description"; ?>

@section('content')
```

I feel like this is a quick and dirty way to get the job done, is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This works as well:

**master.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <meta name="description" content="@yield('description')">
</head>
```

**individual page**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    This is an individual page title
@stop

@section('description')
    This is a description
@stop

@section('content')
```

or if you want to shorten that some more, alternately do this:

**individual page**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'This is an individual page title')
@section('description', 'This is a description')

@section('content')
```

Comment: This is a much better answer.

Comment: I would put a `@if(!empty($description)) ..  @endif` around the meta-tag. Just to avoid a meta-tag with an empty description.

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
<?php View::share('title', 'title'); ?>

...
```

You can also do this:

```
@extends('views.coming-soon.layout', ['title' => 'This is an individual page title'])
```

Comment: Interesting, what is the `View::share();`? Can I do the same for the meta description?

Comment: Those variables are instantiated to be used in whatever place you need in your layout or subviews.

Comment: While this method appears to work (thanks to Antonio, I didn't know you could pass an array with `@extends` to pass variables up the chain), I have a feeling the general idea in these situations is to 'extend' a section (see `@section` and `@parent` in [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating). That said, this works a lot better in 'navigation'-like situations over things like the page title and especially the meta description (due to having to use the Blade syntax from within an HTML attribute which feels really dirty).

Answer (score 2):

Really recommend this:

https://github.com/artesaos/seotools

You pass the information to the the view require the content

```
SEOTools::setTitle($page->seotitle);
SEOTools::setDescription($page->seodescription);
```

Answer (score 1):

no one think that the best way is to create your own class with facade (Site::title(), Site::description etc) and mutators (via Str::macro) that automatically check if title, description etc is in right format (max length, adding categories, defaults, separators, etc) and clone data to others fields (title => og:title, description => og:description) if necessary?

Comment: Could you expand on that in simplistic, newbie-friendly terms?

Comment: No, I do not think that is the best way.  I have yet to engineer a Laravel 4 site that requires a formal facade for view variable management.  I understand the importance of the factors you're mentioning, but I would argue those are specialized needs and should be handled on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: This is a nice approach, when you are working on large scale application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a variable in your title so it's dynamically generated from your DB, I do it like this:

master.blade.php

```
<title>@yield('title')</title>
```

article.blade.php

```
@section( 'title', '' . e($article->title) )
```

It uses https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-e